# Stable cohomology of mapping class group with coefficients in $H^{\otimes n}$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, moduli-spaces, group-cohomology, mapping-class-groups

Let $\text{Mod}_g$ be the mapping class group of a closed oriented genus-$g$ surface $\Sigma_g$ and let $H = H_1(\Sigma_g;\mathbb{Q})$.  Fix some $r \geq 0$.  It is known that the cohomology group $H^k(\text{Mod}_g;H^{\otimes r})$ is independent of $g$ once $g$ is sufficiently large relative to $g$ and $r$.  Does anyone know a concrete description of it?

For $r=0$, this is just the Madsen-Weiss theorem.  For $r \geq 1$, this could be extracted from the paper

E. Looijenga,
Stable cohomology of the mapping class group with symplectic coefficients and of the universal Abel-Jacobi map,
J. Algebraic Geom. 5 (1996), no. 1, 135-150.

However, this paper really answers a much more complicated question where you look at the cohomology in an irreducible algebraic representation of $\text{Sp}(2g,\mathbb{Q})$.  You could assemble this to get information about $H^{\otimes r}$, but given how complicated Looijenga's answer is this would lead to something terrible.  I'm hoping there is a reasonable closed-form answer for these specific representations.

I've worked through Looijenga's argument and extracted the following special case: if $k$ is even, then $H^k(\text{Mod}_g;H) = 0$, while if $k$ is odd of the form $k = 2n-1$, then
$$H^k(\text{Mod}_g;H) = \bigoplus_{i=0}^{n-2} H^{2i}(\text{Mod}_g;\mathbb{Q}).$$
Thanks to Dan Petersen in the comments for pointing out that I had originally screwed this up, as well as a related calculation for $r=2$.

Comment: Your calculations by hand are definitely wrong. The cohomology with coefficients in $H$ does not vanish stably. Neither does the cohomology with coefficients in the two nontrivial representations of weight two.

Comment: One can give a kind of generating series for these cohomology groups in terms of plethysm of symmetric functions, would you be interested in this?

Comment: @DanPetersen: Are you sure?  Remember that we're just working rationally.  The proof for $H$ uses the fact that the universal curve $\mathcal{M}_{g,1} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_g$ is an algebraic fiber bundle with projective fiber, so the spectral sequence for it degenerates.  I think this means that $H^k(\mathcal{M}_{g,1})$ is the direct sum of $H^k(\mathcal{M}_g)$ and $H^{k-1}(\mathcal{M}_g;H)$ and $H^{k-2}(\mathcal{M}_g)$.  But it's easy to see that we also have $H^k(\mathcal{M}_{g,1})$ equal to the direct sum of $H^k(\mathcal{M}_g)$ and $H^{k-2}(\mathcal{M}_g)$ -- the marked (continued)

Comment: point just introduces a new stable generator in $H^2$ corresponding to the first Chern class of the vertical tangent bundle.

Comment: More generally, I would be interested in any nice description.  If a generating function like you describe is the best possible answer, then that's fine with me.

Comment: Stably, the cohomology ring of $M_g$ is a polynomial algebra in the $\kappa$ classes whereas the cohomology ring of $M_{g,n}$ is a polynomial algebra in the $\kappa$ classes as well as the $n$ classes $\psi_1,\ldots,\psi_n$. In your calculation you haven't taken into account the higher powers of $\psi$.

Comment: @DanPetersen: Whoops, you're absolutely right!  I'll work out the correct answer at least for $H$ (maybe it will be a pain now to get $H^{\otimes 2}$) and update the question.

Comment: I recommend to have a look at Appendix B of Randal-Williams' "Cohomology of automorphism groups of free groups with twisted coefficients". The stable description of the graded $\Sigma_q$-module $H^*(\Gamma_g;H^{\otimes q})$ appears in the middle of page 1471.

Comment: @archipelago: Ah, that's exactly what I was looking for.  If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appendix B of Randal-Williams' ["Cohomology of automorphism groups of free groups with twisted coefficients"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00029-017-0311-0) gives a stable description of the graded $\mathbb{Q}[\Sigma_q]$-module $H^*(\Gamma_g;H^{\otimes q})$.

Comment: I assume that you intend to take $k=q$, right?  My understanding of RW's description is that the symmetric group $\Sigma_q$ is acting by permuting the tensor factors in $H^{\otimes q}$.

Comment: Yes, this was a typo.